# How to write to apollo cache from within React component with out losing context of "this"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm having trouble trying to read from apollo cache from within a `react` component the mutation works and writes to my server and returns the data but when passed to my update function it seems to lose the context of this when in `inMemoryCache.js`

- "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.5"
- "react-apollo": "^2.1.4"
- "apollo-boost": "^0.1.7"

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined
>       at ./node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/inMemoryCache.js.InMemoryCache.readQuery

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import trim from "lodash/trim";

import AuthorForm from '../components/author-form';

import ALL_AUTHORS from "../graphql/getPosts.query";
import CREATE_AUTHOR from "../graphql/createAuthor.mutation";

class CreateAuthor extends Component {
  state = {
    errors: false
  };

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(event.target);

    const data = {
      firstName: form.get("firstName"),
      lastName: form.get("lastName")
    };

    if (!data.firstName || !data.lastName) {
      return this.setState({ errors: true });
    }

    this.create({
      firstName: trim(data.firstName),
      lastName: trim(data.lastName)
    });
  }

  async create(variables) {
    const { createAuthor } = this.props;
    this.setState({ errors: false });

    try {
      await createAuthor({
        variables,
        update: (cache, data) => this.updateCache(cache, data)
      })
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ errors: true })
    }
  }

  updateCache({ readQuery, writeQuery }, { data: { createAuthor }, errors }) {
    if (errors) {
      return;
    }
    const { allAuthors } = readQuery({
      query: ALL_AUTHORS,
      defaults: {
        allAuthors: []
      }
    });
    /*eslint-disable*/ console.log(allAuthors);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AuthorForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}/>
        <OnError/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(CREATE_AUTHOR, { name: "createAuthor" })(CreateAuthor);
```

is it to do with me binding this to the onSubmit button? if so what is the proper way to attach a function to a element without losing context of this within the component and still allow apollo cache to function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was losing the context of this because I was deconstructing the first argument. this is what I settled on in the end.

It throw errors when there were no allAuthors on the ROOT_QUERY object so added it to my return statement.

this doesn't feel like an ideal way of updating the cache shouldn't default param passed to readQuery prevent the error thrown.

```
 updateCache(cache, { data: { createAuthor }, errors }) {
    if (errors || !cache.data.data.ROOT_QUERY.allAuthors) {
      return;
    }

    const query = ALL_AUTHORS;

    const { allAuthors } = cache.readQuery({
      query,
      defaults: {
        allAuthors: []
      }
    });

    const data = {
      allAuthors: allAuthors.concat([createAuthor])
    };

    cache.writeQuery({
      query,
      data
    });
  }
```